# PHP con Mongo, dudas con consultas

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

Tengo un código muy similar al de la foto, en la parte que dice `'$gte' => 18` solo quiero reemplazar el 18 por una variable que el usuario introduce. Ya tengo la variable e intenté con `'$gte' => $num` pero no me funciona. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer esto?

```
<?php
$personas = $bd->personas;

$personas->insert(array("nombre" => "Joe",   "edad" => 4));
$personas->insert(array("nombre" => "Sally", "edad" => 22));
$personas->insert(array("nombre" => "Dave",  "edad" => 22));
$personas->insert(array("nombre" => "Molly", "edad" => 87));

$edades = $bd->command(
    array(
        "distinct" => "personas",
        "key"      => "edad",
        "query"    => array("edad" => array('$gte' => 18))
    )
);

foreach($edades['values'] as $edad)
{
    echo "$edad\n";
}
?>
```

Imagen del código: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwOe.png

Comment: No he usado nunca _mongo_, pero hay algo que no me termina de cuadrar en código. La `key $gte` que usas en el array `array('$gte' => 18)` es esa y se usa así? Ya que las comillas simples interpretan texto literal, no variables. De ser una variable lo que esperas, debería ser `array($gte => $num)`

Comment: Lo que comenta @OscarR. tiene buena pinta. Además intentaría hacer un cast del `$num` a int si es el tipo de datos que espera.

Comment: @OscarR. si, es correcto el uso de estos modificadores.

Comment: y tal como indica @MiquelColl necesitas hacer un cast a int de tu variable `intval($num)` ya que mongo diferencia los tipos de datos

Comment: Interesante funcionamiento entonces @PabloAlcantar,  desconocía por completo el uso de este tipo de modificadores, ya que puede generar cierta confusión a primera vista, y más aún cuando está involucrado en una zona que da errores. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @OscarR. de nada! esto es principalmente, por que la forma de comunicarse con mongo es mediante JSON y no se puede poner `<, >, <=, <=, =` como la key. Por esto se usa `$gte = >=`

Comment: @PabloAlcantar, Vale! Ahora entiendo el funcionamiento y la estructura que utiliza.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como te indican en los comentarios, es necesario realizar un cast de tu variable, ya que mongo internamente infiere el tipo de dato guardado y en base a eso realiza las consultas.

tu código quedaría:

```
$edades = $bd->command(
  array(
    "distinct" => "personas",
    "key"      => "edad",
    "query"    => array("edad" => array('$gte' => intval($num) ))
  )
);
```

Comment: Sigo teniendo mis dudas sobre el `'$gte'` si debvería ir sin comilla simple pero tiene pinta que el cast a `int` es la problemática.

Comment: **debe** ir con comillas simples, ya que PHP cuenta con interpolación de variables, es decir, si le pones `"$gte"` (comillas dobles), el intérprete buscará la variable `$gte` y la interpolará en el string, con lo cual tu llamada a mongo llegaría `array('' => intval($num))` . y si llegases a poner **sin** ninguna comilla, haría lo mismo: poner la variable `$gte` que no tienes declarada.